# Django Google Authentication - Login page unformatted

Tags: django, google-oauth

I have a web page built using Django and I just followed a tutorial (https://www.section.io/engineering-education/django-google-oauth/) to add Google Authentication for user registration. The functionality works fine, I added a button that users can click and go to the Google Sign-in Page. However, this page is completely unformatted, and doesn't look like what's in the tutorial (the Google choose your account page that we've probably all seen). I can't for the life of me figure out why my site isn't serving the same formatted page.

I have 2 urls.py files, one in my main app page, and one in a `users` folder. `users/urls.py` looks like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from users import views as user_views
from django.contrib.auth.views import LogoutView

urlpatterns = [
    path('register/', user_views.register, name='register'),
    path('login/', user_views.login_user, name='user-login'),
    path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    path('logout', LogoutView.as_view()),
]
```

In my `settings.py` file, I've added `SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS` , `SITE_ID` and `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` . What else could I be missing that would affect the format of this page?